# Can't seem to build hive for spark

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to run this code in pyspark.

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc) 
datumDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(datumX, schema)
```

But have been receiving this warning:

```
Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o44))
```

I log in to AWS and spin up clusters with this code: `/User/Downloads/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/ec2/spark-ec2 -k name -i /User/Desktop/pemfile.pem login clustername`

However I all the docs I've found involve this commands, which exist in the file
`/users/downloads/spark-1.5.2/` I've run them anyway, and tried logging into was using the ec2 command in that folder after I did. Still, just got the same error

I submit export `SPARK_HIVE=TRUE` before running these commands on my local machine, but I've seen messages saying its deprecated and will be ignored anyway.

Build hive with maven:

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 
    -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package
```

Build hive with sbt

```
 build/sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.3 assembly
```

And another I found

```
./sbt/sbt -Phive assembly
```

I also took the `hive-site.xml file` and put in both the `/Users/Downloads/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/conf folder and the /Users/Downloads/spark-1.5.2/conf`

Still no luck.

I can't seem to run the hive commands no matter what I build it with or how I log in. Is there anything obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Spark binaries are by default build with Hive support. It looks like you have more than one installation (?) and switch Hadoop version from build to build. Is it all expected?

Comment: I downloaded a spark file which needed to be built, then downloaded a prebuilt version after - the two folders . Are you saying this conflict be the reason for Hive not working - and therefore a reasonable solution would be to delete them and then reinstall a prebuilt version of Spark? (I will try this myself tomorrow, of course, just trying to understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had the same error when using a `HiveContext` on a EC2 cluster built with the ec2 scripts that comes with the Spark package (v1.5.2 in my case). Through much trial and error, I found that building a EC2 cluster with the following options got the right version of Hadoop with Hive properly built so that I can use a `HiveContext` in my PySpark jobs:

```
spark-ec2 -k <your key pair name> -i /path/to/identity-file.pem -r us-west-2 -s 2 --instance-type m3.medium --spark-version 1.5.2 --hadoop-major-version yarn  launch <your cluster name>
```

The key parameters here is that you set `--spark-version` to 1.5.2 and `--hadoop-major-version` to `yarn` - even though you aren't using to use Yarn to submit jobs as it forces the hadoop build to be 2.4. Of course, adjust the other parameters as appropriate for your desired cluster.