# which is the easier way to set up ec2 cluster with hadoop and hive?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I am having problems executing the following command:

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

in a EC2 cluster. It works well locally, but not in the cluster.

The cluster was set up with the following command:

```
spark-ec2 -k <your key pair name> -i /path/to/identity-file.pem -r us-west-2 -s 2 --instance-type m3.medium --spark-version 1.5.2 --hadoop-major-version yarn  launch <your cluster name>
```

according to: [Can't seem to build hive for spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231889/cant-seem-to-build-hive-for-spark/40846607#40846607)

Is hive support installed? where can I find the configuration files?
Do I need to compile spark for hive (-Phive) support anyway?

Comment: The easyest way is to use qubole.

Comment: You can use Apache Ambari which has a wizard for hadoop installation.
I downloaded it from Hortonworks and followd their tutorial.
If you need more help with it contact me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to use Spark version 2.0 which have the HiveContext already integrated in the SparkSession.

The key parameters to upload the cluster are --spark-version and hadoop-major-version as here:

```
./spark-ec2 -k <your key pair name> -i /path/to/identity-file.pem -s <number of slaves> -r <region> --instance-type <instance type> --spark-version=2.0.1 --hadoop-major-version yarn launch rcluster
```